# XSLT multiple templates but only gets from last result

Tags: xml, xslt

I am newbie to XML and XSLT and have two different templates but the output I get is from last templates.

The first template output the create html text where data-video-single is false i.e. the value of 0 and second template output the html text where the it two divs i.e. one on the left and second on the right.

I need both text joined together as a single html output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:key name="groups" match="/videos/video" use="data-video-group"/>

    <xsl:template match="/videos">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="single" select="video[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', data-video-group)[1]) and data-video-single=0]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="video" mode="single">

                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="data-video-group"/>
                </h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', data-video-group)">
                    <xsl:if test="data-video-single = '0'">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <p class="featurePic">
                                <img data-video-id="{data-video-id}" data-video-url="{data-video-url}" alt=""></img>
                            </p>
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-heading"/>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-content"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/videos">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="nonSingle" select="video[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', data-video-group)[1]) and data-video-single=1]" />                
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="video" mode="nonSingle">

        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 != 0">
            <div class="featureLeft">
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="data-video-group"/>
                </h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', data-video-group)">
                    <xsl:if test="data-video-single = '1'">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <p class="featurePic">
                                <img data-video-id="{data-video-id}" data-video-url="{data-video-url}" alt=""></img>
                            </p>
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-heading"/>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-content"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>            
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
            <div class="featureRight">
                <h2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="data-video-group"/>
                </h2>

                <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', data-video-group)">
                    <xsl:if test="data-video-single = '1'">
                        <div class="feature">
                            <p class="featurePic">
                                <img data-video-id="{data-video-id}" data-video-url="{data-video-url}" alt=""></img>
                            </p>
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-heading"/>
                            </h3>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="data-video-content"/>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:if>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>                        
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the source xml data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/UserControls/IRISNewRelease/Data/newrelease.xslt"?>
<videos>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>1</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>0</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>ABC GROUP</data-video-group>
        <data-video-groupNote></data-video-groupNote>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 1</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>2</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>0</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>ABC GROUP</data-video-group>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 2</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>3</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>0</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>Company Secretarial</data-video-group>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 3</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>4</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>0</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>Business Tax</data-video-group>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 4</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>5</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>0</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>Personal Tax</data-video-group>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 5</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
    <video>
        <data-video-id>6</data-video-id>
        <data-video-single>1</data-video-single>
        <data-video-group>Personal Tax</data-video-group>
        <data-video-groupNote>Integration with IRIS Personal Tax</data-video-groupNote>
        <data-video-url>VIMEO</data-video-url>
        <data-video-heading>Video Heading 6</data-video-heading>
        <data-video-content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae lacus fermentum vehicula.</data-video-content>
    </video>
</videos>
```

The expected result as below ...

The below result is from the first template i.e. mode = single, if you comment the second template and run it will work fine.

```
<h2>
    Personal Tax</h2>
<div class="feature">
    <p class="featurePic">
        <img data-video-id="50214413" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
    <h3>
        Simplified Client Data Entry</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
        lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
</div>
<div class="feature">
    <p class="featurePic">
        <img data-video-id="50214135" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
    <h3>
        IRIS Personal Tax and Payroll Integration</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
        lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
</div>
```

This is the result from second template i.e. mode = nonSingle, if you comment the first template and run this result will work fine.

```
<div class="featureLeft">
    <h2>
        Accounts Production</h2>
    <div class="feature">
        <p class="featurePic">
            <img data-video-id="50220365" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
        <h3>
            Companies House iXBRL e-filing</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
            lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature">
        <p class="featurePic">
            <img data-video-id="50220516" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
        <h3>
            IRIS Accounts Production supports companies limited by guarantee</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
            lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="featureRight">
    <h2>
        Company Secretarial</h2>
    <div class="feature">
        <p class="featurePic">
            <img data-video-id="50220436" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
        <h3>
            Company name change for Companies House</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
            lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="featureLeft">
    <h2>
        Business Tax</h2>
    <div class="feature">
        <p class="featurePic">
            <img data-video-id="50214325" data-video-url="VIMEO" alt=""></p>
        <h3>
            IRIS Business Tax Client Account Overview</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo tellus vitae
            lacus fermentum vehicula.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I have both on the file it will only show last template result instead of the both templates.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to provide the source XML document (as small as possible, please), and the wanted exact result for that source XML document. Please, edit the question and provide this important and now missing information.

Comment: You contradict yourself. First you say "The expected result is below..." and then in complete contradiction, you proceed to give 2 listings, both apparently not what you want, and no expected result. Even your output listing contains data (eg data-video-id="50220365") which bears no relationship to the input document.

Comment: Asking a good XSLT question on StackOverflow is really simple. Just provide a simple demonstrative sample input and the expected output that should result from that input.

Comment: Also your first featureLeft div has a different structure to your second featureLeft div. There is no explanation why, or rules provided to say which input nodes match to which of the two competing feature div output structures.

Answer (score 0):

I cant give you a fitted solution because you forgot to provide a sample input document and expected output document. I can however, give you a general pattern of a solution. You will need to adjust it to your needs and complete the sequence constructor of the last template.

Generally, the idea to move branching away from explicit branch instructions (xsl:if etc) and into template match patterns. Also move looping control away from xsl:for-each and into template processing (xsl:apply-templates).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="groups" match="/videos/video" use="data-video-group"/>

<xsl:template match="/videos">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="video[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', data-video-group)[1])]" mode="head"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="video" mode="head">
  <h2><xsl:value-of select="data-video-group" /></h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groups', data-video-group)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="video[data-video-single=0]">
  <!-- Content for "data-video-single = False" case. -->
  <div class="feature">
    <p class="featurePic">
      <img data-video-id="{data-video-id}" data-video-url="{data-video-url}" alt=""></img>
    </p>
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="data-video-heading" /></h3>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="data-video-content" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="video[data-video-single!=0]">
  <!-- Your content for "data-video-single = True" case goes here! -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have tried your xslt style-sheet but I did not work for me as you have head as separate template, in my html output I need a <div> with class "featureLeft" and "featureRight" i.e. i need to position first group on the left and second group on the right.

Comment: Yes, that is because I wrote this answer in response to your original edit which did not have the use case. I will soon update the solution according to your new information.

Comment: Ok, I will wait until you have provided the expected output.